# finding mutual friends in a cypher statement starting with three or more persons

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to build a cypher statement for neo4j where I know 2-n starting nodes by name and need to find a node (if any) that can be reached by all of the starting nodes.

At first I tought it was similar to the "Mutual Friend" situation that could be handled like 
`(start1)-[*..2]->(main)<-[*..2]-(start2)` 
but in my case I often have more then 2 starting points up around 6 that I know by name.

So basically I am puzzled by how i can include the third, fourth and so on node into the cypher to be able to find a commmon root amongst them.

[image: how do I find Anders]

In the above Example from the neo4j Website I would need a path starting with 'Dilshad', 'Becky' and 'Cesar' to check if they have a common friend (Anders) excluding 'Filipa' and 'Emil' as they are not friends of all three.

So far I would create a statement programmatically that looks like

```
MATCH (start1 {name:'Person1'}), (start2 {name:'Person2'}), 
(start3 {name: 'Person3'}), (main) 
WHERE (start1)-[*..2]->(main) AND 
(start2)-[*..2]->(main) AND 
(start3)-[*..2]->(main) RETURN distinct main
```

But I was wondering if there is a more elegant / efficient way in cypher possibly where I could use the list of names as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query shown in your question is building a [cartesian product](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/cross-product-cypher-queries-will-not-perform-well/) because you are matching multiple disconnected patterns.

Instead of `MATCH` all nodes separately and use `WHERE` to restrict the relations between these nodes you can do something like:

```
MATCH (start1 {name:'Person1'})-[*..2]->(main),
(start2 {name:'Person2'})-[*..2]->(main), 
(start3 {name: 'Person3'})-[*..2]->(main)
RETURN main
```

The above query will be more efficient because it will match only the required pattern. Note that when you are doing `MATCH (start1 {name:'Person1'}), (start2 {name:'Person2'}), (start3 {name: 'Person3'}), (main)`, the part `(main)` is matching all nodes of your graph because no restrictions to this are specified. You can use [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) with your query to see it more clearly.

Comment: thank you for your help, it is indeed more efficient and even a bit easier to produce with a variable number of starting points.

Comment: Hi @StefanKüppers you are welcome! If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.